# UPDATE database.table SET name='Tesla' WHERE ID=420; Not updating on slaves

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I have recently realized that updates made in the manner below (without a prior declaration 'use database') on my MySQL master have not updated on my slaves.

```
UPDATE database.table SET name='Tesla' WHERE ID=420;
```

Is there any command that I can execute on my master or slaves to make them execute all of these past update queries or will I have to re-setup replication on each slave?

Comment: I don't believe that's the same question. My slaves have not lost data due to a disconnection as is the case with the question that you sight. My slaves are up to date with all new records added and their log records seem to be "in sync". The only thing that my slaves lack is record updates of certain queries and my question is whether those specific queries can be passed on to my slave.

Comment: If anybody else has this problem I am finding out that it likely has to do with binlog-do-db, binlog-ignore-db, replicate-do-db, and replicate-ignore-db when setting up replication. https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/